# Where to start line breaking in Python?

Tags: python, line-breaks, pep8

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) does not seem to prescribe whether line breaking should start from the *beginning* or from the *end* of the line, in order to stay within the 79 character limit.

For instance where should I break this line?

```
long_function_name_1(long_function_name_2(long_function_name_3(long_function_name_4(long_function_name_5(long_function_name_6(long_function_name_7(long_function_name_8(args))))))))
```

From the beginning?

```
long_function_name_1(
    long_function_name_2(
        long_function_name_3(
            long_function_name_4(
                long_function_name_5(
                    long_function_name_6(
                        long_function_name_7(long_function_name_8(args))))))))
```

Or from the end?

```
long_function_name_1(long_function_name_2(long_function_name_3(
    long_function_name_4(long_function_name_5(long_function_name_6(
        long_function_name_7(long_function_name_8(args))))))))
```

I am particularly interested in the rationale behind the recommendation of one form over the other.

Comment: Do note that PEP8 and readability / clean code don't always go hand-in-hand; PEP8, for example, is against using multiple whitespaces for vertical alignment - which can be very useful. The main advantage with PEP8 I'd say is enforcing _consistency_ so that it's easier to compare code across different editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I go with the beginning

```
long_function_name_1(
    long_function_name_2(
        long_function_name_3(
            long_function_name_4(args))))
```

Indentation makes it clear what function accepts what. If there is more than one argument then they'll form a 'column' (in that case would be better to move the ending parenthesis to a new line too).

Comment: Why do you choose this?

Comment: Indentation makes it clear what function accepts what. If there is more than one argument then they'll form a 'column' (in that case would be better to move the ending parenthesis to a new line too).

Comment: Interesting, that sounds like a reasonable argument, thank you. Could add this to your answer?

Answer (score 4):

First, keep in mind that PEP8 is a *guide*, not a *prescription*. Practically speaking Python code is valid as long as it meets the language specification. In practice, I would say "as long as CPython doesn't complain, it's OK".

Use an program like [`yapf`](https://pypi.org/project/yapf/) or [`black`](https://pypi.org/project/black/) to format your Python code. That way you don't have to worry about the details. Set up a shortcut in your editor to call the formatter, or call it automatically before you check in a file in your revision control software.

I would suggest setting the acceptable line length for those tools to a value around 90. The outdated 79 character limit in PEP8 comes from low resolution monitors (and going back to hardware terminals and teletypes) that are hardly relevant today. Strictly adhering to this limit in modern Python code with list comprehensions and f-strings can actually make your code *less* readable. Watch Raymond Hettinger's [beyond PEP8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M). See also [his post](https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-ideas/54883/) that was linked in the comments:

> PEP 8 is mostly about readability.  However, the line length limit often seems to cause less readable code.

With such settings, `yapf` makes it into:

```
long_function_name_1(
    long_function_name_2(long_function_name_3(long_function_name_4(args)))
)
```

Comment: +1 for the `yapf` example. I am particularly interested about the rationale behind recommending one form over the other.

Comment: "setting the acceptable line length for those tools to a value around 90" - very bad advise. It directly breaks PEP's rule of 79 characters limit https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: @sanyash It does, and it should - the "rule" is a default, and is configurable to meet developer needs. 79 isn't a universal optimal.

Comment: The rule can be configured but it is not a good idea to do it. "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules." - Zen of Python.

Comment: @sanyash Providing some _rationale_ to your position rather than chanting "rules are rules" would be more helpful - as latter is rather dogmatic and antithetical to effective programming.

Comment: Everybody wants to break the rules. This answer says "lets have 90 characters", your coworker says "I am ok with 120", your next coworker says "why not 150?" and so on. There will be a great mess if everyody will break PEP rules.

Comment: The line length of 79 as put forth by PEP8 was written in a time where monitor resolutions were very small and 79 was intended to ensure that a line didn't extend off the right side of the screen for developers. That's mostly a moot point now, since resolutions are so much higher. See [this thread](https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-ideas/54883/) in Python-ideas endorsing the idea by none less than Raymond Hettinger

Comment: @sanyash The rule is bad and should have been updated years ago. Adherence to it now is equally bad. If you start a new Python project, set a larger line wrap length

Comment: Another point on 79 is, different projects have different average variable length names; for those with longer names, conforming to 79 leads to cluttering and sacrificing much readability

Comment: Thanks for the 79 max length debate, but I think this is a bit off topic. I am interested in *why* do you choose line breaking from the beginning.